# Push an item to the bottom of its parent, without overlap?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have an element extending at least across the full viewport vertically (min-height of 100vh). This element has two childs, a menu item (basically a formatted list of links) and another element.

I'd like to push the latter element to the bottom of the parent one, without overlapping the menu, across resolution changes.

For now I am using the position absolute solution https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WGpyYa. But it turns out the "red" element can overlap the menu in some configuration.

HTML & CSS code:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.parentContainer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.pushBottom {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentContainer">
  <ul>
    <li>foobar</li>
    <li>foobar</li>
    <li>foobar</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="pushBottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

How would you do to push the red element to the bottom of the parent "yellow" one, without overlapping the menu?

Thanks!

Comment: It look like you want a list that can contain an indeterminate number of items, but you want the red box a fixed size. Is that correct? What do you want to happen to the red box in the case that the viewport is short enough for them to overlap? Should the red box get smaller? Should the list overlap the box? Should both items retain their height and cause vertical scrolling on the full page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy if you are using a `flexbox` on the parent container:

1. Remove the absolute positioning for the `red` section.
2. Add `display: flex` to the `pushBottom` and use `flex-direction: column` to flex vertically.
3. Use `justify-content: space-between` to keep the `pushBottom` at the bottom at all display sizes.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}
.parentContainer {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.pushBottom {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parentContainer">
  <ul>
    <li>foobar</li>
    <li>foobar</li>
    <li>foobar</li>
  </ul>
  <div class="pushBottom">
  </div>
</div>
```

Check this out and let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

Comment: @Phyks please let me know if this solved you problem... Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it matches perfectly my use case! Thanks!